# Parallax scrolling with disappearing vertical line

Tags: jquery, html, css, sticky

I'm working through developing a site for a client and I'm stuck on something that is proving to be quite the challenge for me. I am including a video link showing the effect I'm trying to accomplish below in addition to a codepen showing what I've done thus far.

I found a plugin that makes the header sticky until the user scrolls until a certain point, but my biggest challenge is the effect with the vertical line. The things I've tried force the line to scroll up with the content, and the line should get smaller as the div gets smaller, as shown in the video. Is there an elegant way to create this effect without a ton of ugly javascript coding?

Edit for clarification: The video shows a wireframe concept. There will be background images for each section of the site and it will use background-attachment:fixed to create the parallax effect. The background image will also scale to fit the full-width/height of the screen.

Video Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kX_MHb8h-r8&feature=youtu.be

```js
$(function() {
  return $("[data-sticky_column]").stick_in_parent({
    parent: "[data-sticky_parent]"
  });
});
$(window).on("resize", (function(_this) {
  return function(e) {
    return $(document.body).trigger("sticky_kit:recalc");
  };
})(this));
```

```css
h1 {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  color: #ff0000;
}
.title-container {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.fixedbkg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.bg1 {
  background-color: #acacac;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
.bg2 {
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
.bg3 {
  background-color: #595959;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg1 fixedbkg" data-sticky_parent>
    <div class="title-container" data-sticky_column>
      <h1>Title 1</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg2 fixedbkg" data-sticky_parent>
    <div class="title-container" data-sticky_column>
      <h1>Title 2</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg3 fixedbkg" data-sticky_parent>
    <div class="title-container" data-sticky_column>
      <h1>Title 3</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CodePen Link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waMwxP

Comment: If the backgrounds are solid colors, as in the video, then you can just give a thick border-top to the second div, with the color of the first div's background, so that it hides the line of first div a certain distance above the top of the second div content.

Comment: Thanks, but it will actually be an image and the image size will be full screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the old `background-position: fixed` trick.

Here is an example I made for you:

http://www.googledrive.com/host/0B1rSHSpIdbJdSm16ZUwyMDZlTUk

It doesn't convert between hiding and scrolling the first box halfway through, when you reach the text, because you need Javascript to do that, and it's just a quick and dirty demo. (I can't even put a proper Doctype on top otherwise something breaks!)

**But it does hide the white line as you're scrollyng, using only CSS.**

It's an old trick. This famous page is from 2002, it uses `background-position: fixed` to simulate an opacity filter that doesn't exist in CSS, the "bathroom window" effect:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/complexspiral/glassy.html

Source code for my example above:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSS-only line hiding effect</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Futura;
        }
        p {
            width: 25em;
        }
        .pad {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 2em;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        #one {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            background: black url(https://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/CambridgeBotanicGarden_ROW8585973051_1920x1080.jpg);
            color: white;
        }
        #two {
            z-index: 1;
            position: relative;
            background: #67c3e8 url(https://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/KokneseCastle_ROW14801377853_1920x1080.jpg);
        }
        #coverOne {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 2em;
            top: -2em;
            left: 0;
            background: black url(https://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/CambridgeBotanicGarden_ROW8585973051_1920x1080.jpg) fixed;
        }
        .line {
            position: absolute;
            top: 18em;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 5em;
            width: 5px;
            background: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="pad" id="one">
        <h1>ONE</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pad"></div>
    <div class="pad" id="two">
        <div id="coverOne"></div>
        <h1>TWO</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't believe I'd feel comfortable using this on a commercial site I'm developing. I like the idea behind it, but I worry it won't work properly across a wide variety of browsers and devices.

I also want to add that I am OK with using JavaScript/jQuery to accomplish this task.